# Python: How can I make more variables from a string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, variables, char

I have **str="TextHere"** I want to split that variable into letters and then make a different variable for each letter. How can I do this if I don´t know how many letters are in my string?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: you can cast the string to a list e.g. list(str) to get a list of each individual chatacter. Length doesn't matter.

Comment: Why? Also, how will you know what to call each variable, and how will you know what each variable is called when you want to use them later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the built_in [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)  Function

```
str = "Hello"
>>> list(str)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

iterating over characters of the string:

```
charlist = []
for character in string:
    charlist.append(character)
```

pythonic way:

```
charlist = [character for character in string]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule creating an unknown number of variables is a bad idea, because it makes the scope opaque. As an alternative, create a dictionary, and store the values in the dictionary:

```
char_dict = {}
for char in string:
    var_name = create_var_name(char)
    char_dict[var_name] = get_value(char)
```

`create_var_name` is whatever code you have to name the variable based on the character. `get_value` is whatever code you have to determine the value of the variable.